# Bind My DataGridView to a Ref Cursor

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I have been trying to connect my DataGridView to the output of a stored procedure that is a ref cursor. I searched a lot of websites and blogs, and could not solve the problem I am encountering.
This is the code I used for creating the procedure in Oracle 11g :

```
    Create or replace package testpkg 
as  
    type T_cursor is ref cursor;
    procedure cursor1 (IDp in number, records out T_cursor);
end testpkg;
/

create or replace package body testpkg as 
    procedure cursor1 (IDp in number, records out T_cursor)
    is
        temp_records T_Cursor;
    begin 
        open temp_records for
            select status,at_time
            from shift_records
            where employee_id=IDp;
        records:=temp_records;
    end cursor1;
end testpkg;
/
```

this is the code I used in c#, I am desiging a windows for application, EmpSal is the DataGridView name :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connString);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "testpkg.cursor1";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("IDp", OracleDbType.Int16);
cmd.Parameters["IDp"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["IDp"].Value = ID;

cmd.Parameters.Add("records", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
cmd.Parameters["records"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);


DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
da.Fill(dt);

BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;


EmpSal.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

I know this C# may not seem very logic, it is because I brought it from many blogs and modified it a lot. But still getting this error :

```
InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

this error was at : "da.Fill(dt);"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not openning your connection object. (**On a side note the OracleConnection is a deprecated class.)

This link should give you a good example to work with (for .Net Framework 4.5)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

You should end up with something approaching:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connString))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "testpkg.cursor1";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("IDp", OracleDbType.Int16);
    cmd.Parameters["IDp"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["IDp"].Value = ID;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("records", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
    cmd.Parameters["records"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);        
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure no problem, glad to be of service. Also... you may want to edit/delete the connection string from your post. Esp. if it is the one you use in RL. Just noticed that.